# Swift MetalKit unknknown return type MTKMesh.newMeshes

Tags: swift, assets, metal, metalkit

Up until now I have been following a tutorial (released around the time of Metal 1), to learn Metal.  I haven't encountered any errors I couldn't figure out until this point.  I am trying to execute this code

```
var meshes: [AnyObject]?
//code
let device = MTLDevice() //device is fine
let asset = MDLAsset() //asset works fine
do{
    meshes = try MTKMesh.newMeshes(asset: asset, device: device)
} catch //...
```

The error i'm getting is `Cannot assign value of type '(modellOMeshes: [MDLMesh], metalKitMeshes: [MTKMesh])' to type '[AnyObject]?'`

What is type of `MTKMesh.newMeshes`, and how can I store it in a variable?  I tried casting it `as! [AnyObject]`, but then xcode tells me that this cast would fail every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of that method is `([MDLMesh], [MTKMesh])`, a tuple comprised of an array of `MTLMesh`es and an array of `MTKMesh`es. The reason for this is that you might want the original collection of `MDLMesh` objects contained in the asset, in addition to the `MTKMesh` objects that are created for you.

So, you can declare `meshes` like this:

```
var meshes: ([MDLMesh], [MTKMesh])
```

Or, if you don't care about the original `MDLMesh`es, you can "destructure" the tuple to get just the portion you care about into a variable of type `[MTKMesh]`:

```
var meshes: [MTKMesh]
(_, meshes) = try MTKMesh.newMeshes(asset: asset, device: device)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the function signature and the compiler error clearly show, the return type is `(modelIOMeshes: [MDLMesh], metalKitMeshes: [MTKMesh])`, so you should declare `meshas` accordingly:

```
var meshes: (modelIOMeshes: [MDLMesh], metalKitMeshes: [MTKMesh])?
```

The type is a named tuple containing two `Array`s, holding `MDLMesh` and `MTKMesh` instances respectively.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't phrase my misunderstanding well. I saw what the return type was, I just wasn't sure what that type is. To me, it looks like the arguments of a function, could you explain what that type is?

Comment: @GabeSpound The type is a named tuple containing two `Array`s, holding `MDLMesh` and `MTKMesh` instances respectively.